# Comparing 2 csv files using powershell

Tags: powershell, comparison

i have written a script which gives generates a file with all the possible pin-codes combinations (0000-9999) then it brings back all the pin-codes that are unavailable (already assigned to AD users) but in the end i want to develop this script to make it genertate a third file with available pin-codes through comparing the first 2 files (the file with all the possible combinations and the file with the combinations that are already taken) the script is this

```
Import-Module Activedirectory 
$all = '0000'..'9999' | out-file C:\TEMP\test\NewGroup9.txt
$re = [regex]'ixi:\+49.*(\d{4})'    
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties ProxyAddresses |  
  Select-Object @{Name = 'ixi'; Expression = {$re.Match($_.ProxyAddresses).Groups[1].Value}} | 
    Where-Object { $_.ixi.Trim() } | export-csv C:\TEMP\test\NewGroup14.csv -Delimiter ";" -notypeinformation -Encoding "UTF8"
Get-Content C:\TEMP\test\NewGroup14.csv | % { $_ -replace 'ixi', '' } | 
  sort -Descending | Set-Content C:\TEMP\test\NewGroup17.csv
compare-object -ReferenceObject $(Get-Content C:\TEMP\test\NewGroup9.txt) -DifferenceObject $(get-content C:\TEMP\test\NewGroup17.csv) -IncludeEqual | 
  Where-Object SideIndicator -eq '<=' |
    Export-Csv C:\TEMP\test\NewGroup13.csv -Delimiter ";" -notypeinformation -Encoding "UTF8"
```

the comparision i wrote isn't working , it keeps giving back the same result as the file with all the combinations!! i would appreciate any help thanks

Comment: Your file `C:\TEMP\test\NewGroup9.txt` won't have leading zeroes for the numbers below 1000 because  the strings `'0000'..'9999'` are converted to integers first. As out-file leaves not output `$all` is empty.  Your code doesn't make sense once creating a csv and then opening it as text.

Comment: @LotPings.... very helpful. since i'm here to learn i already know my script has errors but i was hoping for some kind of help and direction not just pointing out the errors dude :) . thanks for the reply anyways

Answer (score 0):

As you want to compare all numbers storing them in a file is IMO worthless

```
$all = 0..9999|%{"{0:D4}" -f $_}
# or alternatively
# $all = 0..9999|%{$_.ToString('0000')}
```

This could work (untested)

```
$re = [regex]'ixi:\+49.*(\d{4})'

$used = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties ProxyAddresses |
  Where ProxyAddressess -match $re |
    Select-Object @{N='ixi';E={$Matches.Groups[1].Value}}|
      Select-Object -ExpandProperty ixi

$UnUsed = Compare-Object ($used|sort) $all | 
  Select-Object -Expandproperty InputObject
```

You can save the vars $Used/$UnUsed to a file with Set-Content.